# How to get data attributes in vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2, vue.js

I have a button, and a modal is poped up when it is clicked. The data in the modal is passed with data attributes for the button.

My button,

```
<button class="edit-modal btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#editModal" :data-id=item.id :data-name=item.name>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
                            </button>
```

It has some data attributes like `id` and `name`.

My modal,

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">ID:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fid" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="n">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn actionBtn btn-success"
                            @click.prevent="updateItem()" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Update <span id="footer_action_button"
                                class='glyphicon glyphicon-check'> </span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
                            data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Actually, am doing with javascript, and the modal is displaying id and name as I wanted. And i also need to pass those data attributes to the `update()` function.

How to workaround in `vuejs` with data attributes.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-modal', function() {
            $('#fid').val($(this).data('id'));
            $('#n').val($(this).data('name'));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if it's a workaround but what you can do is to create a [modal](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html) component and then pass data to it through [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props) or better yet by using [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) like in modal example I've linked.

This should point you in the right direction.